# including jquery.ui 1.6 directly from theme.info

Tags: 6, javascript

It is possible? because i've tried to include jquery ui library through drupal.org/project/jquery_ui module (followed instructions in readme.txt) but that library won't show up in source code. What's the problem?

Should i go for jquery_ui module or i can include that script through .info file?

Jquery ui version = "6.x-1.5"
Downloaded jquery ui library 1.6

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to include jQuery UI, from [README.txt](http://drupalcode.org/project/jquery_ui.git/blob/refs/heads/6.x-1.x:/README.txt):

In your module, call the following function:

```
jquery_ui_add($files);
```

For example:

```
jquery_ui_add(array('ui.draggable', 'ui.droppable', 'ui.sortable'));
jquery_ui_add('ui.sortable');  // For a single file
```

Comment: i'm not using it for my own module. I want that library just for additional effects.

Comment: You can't just add this library without any module. From README.txt: "This module is more-or-less a utility module that should simply be required by other modules that depend on jQuery UI being available. It doesn't do anything on its own."